# Select Values Based On Most Recent Date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a currency table which is updated every few months. I'm trying to pull out only the latest numbers based on the date. However, it doesn't seem to matter what filter or data type convertor I put on it. I can't pull out my unique list.

I'm not sure how to copy over the table format. There are only the following three columns:

```
Date,
CCY,
Rate
```

The table is designed with this date format:

```
2014-01-06 12:07:38.000 GBP   1.65459525585175
```

Any help would be much appreciate.

Answer (score 2):

Having table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ExRate](
    [Date] [datetime] NULL,
    [CCY] [char](3) NULL,
    [Rate] [decimal](12, 6) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

The correct code is:

```
with cte1 as
(
Select Date, CCY, Rate, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by CCY order by Date desc) rn1
from ExRate
)
select * from cte1 where rn1=1
```